# Userscript to restore normal link click behavior to open in a new tab when ctrl+clicked

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Using Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, how can I have listed synonyms (which are links) at [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/test) open in a new tab when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicked, or a new window when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+clicked? Currently, it opens <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicked and <kbd>Strl</kbd>+clicked links in the same tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site breaks the standard link behavior, which is a very bad thing to do, by attaching its own primitive `click` handlers that don't support modifier keys.

Sometimes you can use `jQuery('a').off('click')` but a universal approach is:

1. Attach a click listener on `window`, the topmost DOM object, before the site attaches its own listeners: use `@run-at document-start` metadata key.
2. Specify `true` for the *useCapture* parameter of addEventListener to intercept the event at the very start of the *capturing* phase from `window` to the click target. Thus we additionally increase the chances of interception before it *bubbles* to the element on which the site listens for click events (could be anything, from stuff inside `a` to `window`) with a standard non-capturing listener.
3. Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the subsequently attached site listeners from seeing the click event.
4. Protect legitimate link-based site functionality by skipping dummy links with self-redirects via `#` in target link `href` and/or by limiting the CSS selector of the click target to the content area.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Restore links behavior
// @match   *://www.thesaurus.com/*
// @run-at  document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var link = e.target.closest('a');
    //var link = e.target.closest('#content a'); // limit to the #content area
    if (link && link.getAttribute('href') != '#') {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Good, but this will also break desired menus and buttons.  You should scope the links to reduce side effects.  Something like `if(e.target.closest('.synonyms a'))`, for example. (Specific to that site)

Comment: Indeed. In this case even `#content a` might work but with the `#`-checking it's not needed apparently.

Comment: @wOxxOm, that's awesome, thank you. Are there any side-effects I can expect from this?

Comment: Well, you can become addicted to this userscript and allow it to run on more sites...

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, your solution works like a charm. I actually have a follow-up question, if you'd be so kind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637715/using-grease-tampermonkey-how-can-i-have-the-currently-viewed-definition-at-dic

Comment: That new question doesn't seem to have a potential to be generally useful like this one, for which I already had an existing solution, so personally I'm not interested.