# Using grease/tampermonkey, how can I have the currently viewed definition at Dictionary.com open at Thesaurus.com?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Using Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, how can I have the currently viewed definition at Dictionary.com open at Thesaurus.com (and vice versa) when [the links circled in red are clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrTfs.png).

I see that I can use `window.location.pathname` to retrieve "/browse/test" or whatever word is being searched, which I can then put on the opposite link's hostname.

The HTML of the Thesaurus.com link: `<a href="http://www.thesaurus.com/" data-linkid="qxnxzj">Thesaurus.com</a>`

The HTML of the Dictionary.com link: `<a href="http://www.dictionary.com/" data-linkid="tqks0v">Dictionary.com</a>`

So I was going to either select it with `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='http://www.thesaurus.com']");` or `document.querySelectorAll('[data-linkid=qxnxzj]');`

I was concerned about the latter method of selection, just in case the data-linked was changed by the company's web developer.

However, ultimately, I am still uncertain of how to implement this. Do I listen for all clicks on the `document`, or just on `<a>` tags, etc.? What is the most efficient way to do this?

---

Furthermore, how can I have these links open in a new tab when ctrl+clicked, or a new window when shift+clicked? Currently, it opens ctrl+clicked and shift+clicked links in the same browser tab.

Comment: This is not a script writing service.  Try to solve the problem yourself and then show what you did in the question.  Also, try to make the question more generally applicable. ... Hints:  (1) see the original edit of your previously accepted answer, (2) See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/), (3) jQuery's `.text()`, (4) jQuery's `.attr()`.

Comment: @BrockAdams, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow code was able to fully achieve all goals outlined in my question:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Restore links behavior at Thesaurus.com
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://www.thesaurus.com/*
// @match        *://www.dictionary.com/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-linkid]').forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('data-linkid'));

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var link = e.target.closest('a');
        //var link = e.target.closest('#content a'); // limit to the #content area
        var path = window.location.pathname; // /browse/myword

        if (link && link.getAttribute('href') != '#') {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        if (link && link.getAttribute('href') == 'http://www.thesaurus.com/') {
            link.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.thesaurus.com' + path);
        }
        else if (link && link.getAttribute('href') == 'http://www.dictionary.com/') {
            link.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.dictionary.com' + path);
        }
    }, true);

})();
```